# Subquery Connecting unique ID to name trouble

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, mysql-workbench

I have two tables in question. I am trying to find the names of the pilots who had more than 3 hires assigned in 2018.

taxiPilot Table

```
p_id  p_lname  p_fname  p_city  
043   Smith    John     Dayton
044   Doe      Jane     Cincinnati
```

Assignment Table

```
p_id  AT_id   HireNo  AssignDate  City
043   BU78    1       11/29/2018  Dayton
044   BU89    2       11/29/2018  Akron
```

This is just a brief example of the data I do have.

I have tried the following

```
select p_fname, p_lname
from taxiPilot tp
join assignment a on tp.p_id = a.p_id
where a.p_id IN (Select count(a.p_id)
from assignment
where AssignDate between "01/01/2018" and "12/31/2018"
group by a.p_id
having count(a.p_id) > 3);
```

This results in a blank table

I am expecting to get the following

```
p_fname  p_lname  count(a.p_id)
Joe      Smith    5
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do on this?:

```
    Select count(a.p_id)
from assignment
where AssignDate between "01/01/2018" and "12/31/2018"
group by a.p_id
having count(a.p_id) > 3
```

this will retunr a number (because of the count) but will not match with the ID of the assignment.

Comment: Hi I am trying to pull their first and last name in addition to the amount of times they were hired.

Answer (score 0):

in that case it would be something like this (i didn't test it):

```
select p_fname, p_lname, (Select count(a.p_id)
from assignment
where AssignDate between "01/01/2018" and "12/31/2018"
group by a.p_id
having count(a.p_id) > 3)
from taxiPilot tp
join assignment a on tp.p_id = a.p_id
;
```

Comment: This is on the right track, however, the count shows up as null.

Answer (score 0):

I think simple aggregation will work if you cast the dates.
[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s9agsDfPQ9DxFY8kuxUrAY/0)

```
select p_fname, p_lname, count(*)
  from taxiPilot tp 

join assignment a 
  on tp.p_id = a.p_id

where a.AssignDate between CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATETIME) 
                       and CAST('2018-12-31' AS DATETIME)
group by p_fname, p_lname
having count(*) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with paste as (
select 
p_id, count(a.p_id) 
from assignment
group by 1
having count(*) > 3
)

select p_lname,  p_fname, max(HireNo)
from taxiPilot 
where p_id in (select p_id from paste)
group by 1, 2
```

Haven't tried though.

Answer (score 0):

First, you were on the right idea, but your sub-query was not correlated to just one pilot.  You just grabbed all assignments between the date, but had no correlation of which pilot.  So you could have had a count of 273 across all pilots.

Instead, you could add the pilot id in the subquery and THEN join outside of that.  This way you are not trying to pull all pilots.  Get those that qualified, THEN get the names.

```
select
      tp.p_fname,
      tp.p_lname,
      PQ.NumHires
   from
      ( select a.p_id, count(*) NumHires
           from Assignment a
           where a.AssignDate between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'
           group by a.p_id 
           having count(*) > 3) PQ
         JOIN taxiPilot tp
            on PQ.p_id = tp.p_id
   order by
      tp.p_lname,
      tp.p_fname
```